# Variable is correct, but test case does not execute

Tags: c, if-statement, testcase

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[] = {23, 43, 12, 17, 204, 99, 16};
#define TOTAL_ELEMENTS (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]))

int main()
{
        int test = -1;

        if (test <= TOTAL_ELEMENTS)
        {
                printf("Hello, got here!\n");
        }
}
```

When I compile this code (with `gcc main.c -Wall` (no warnings!)), and run it, the `printf` fails to execute. I mean, `test` = `-1`, and that is definitely smaller than the size of the array (7 digits). Where is the bug?

Comment: Try `long long test = -1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bug was in the difference between `unsigned` and `signed`. Specifically, the defined variable `TOTAL_ELEMENTS`'s type is `unsigned int` (`sizeof` returns `unsigned` because a size can never be negative). The test is comparing a `signed int` with an `unsigned int`. That fails because `test` is promoted to `unsigned`. -1 turned into unsigned becomes a large positive integer, thus making the `if` conditional return false.

If you compile with `gcc main.c -Wall -Wextra` it will warn.

Comment: Strictly, `sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t`, which is an unsigned type, but is not usually `unsigned` (as in `unsigned int`).  But yes, the value `-1` is converted to `size_t`, and the converted value of `-1` in a two's-complement system is the largest value representable by `size_t`.

Comment: For this and other reasons, I have learned to always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to show all warnings and also to convert them to errors to force me to fix them. [I wrote about this and recommend it in my repo here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world#additional-c-and-c-build-notes-ex-wgcc-or-clang-compilers).

Comment: " the defined variable TOTAL_ELEMENTS's type is unsigned int" --> C does not specify that.  `size_t` is some _unsinged_ type.  Could be `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, or others.